# How do I refer original object values from copied object?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have cloned an object. Do I have any way to access the original object from copied object?

I have to refer original objects association from copied objects.

Comment: pls provide some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, from cloned object you can't get the original object back but in your method you will have reference to the original object. E.g .

```
class ClonableClass implements Clonable {

....

 protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
//Code to clone
}
}

class Test {

public testClone(){
    ClonableClass  obj = new ClonableClass (); //Main object
    ClonableClass  cloneObject = (ClonableClass)obj .clone(); //Your clone object
}
}
```